# Why am I getting this out of range error

Tags: c++, string, debugging, c++11, io

I have a file that contains a set range of numbers for example 20. The contents of the file are social security numbers, I am trying to erase every '-'. Though while going through the file I am receiving the following error.

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string

Here is the code

```
string str;
ifstream inFile (fName);
//fName= name of the file
if (inFile.is_open())
{
    while ( getline (inFile,str) )
    {

        cout << str << endl;
        str.erase(3,1);//erasing first '-'
        str.erase(5,1);//erasing second '-'
        cout << str << endl;
    }
    inFile.close();
}

else
    cout << "Unable to open file";
```

Comment: Are you sure the content of `str` is correct?

Comment: @Mikejones Do a `cout << str << endl;` before erasing the string, and verify that indeed the string represents an SSN. The code is perfectly fine otherwise, so your file is probably storing something else.

Comment: @vsoftco its works fine, even outputs all the file contents. It just crashes as soon as its finish. for instance when adding a cout to the start of the loop, and end of the loop the first few outputs are .
500-18-7127
500187127
053-54-3256
053543256

Comment: Yeah you need to output what `str` was for the times it *didn't* work. Use a debugger.

Comment: @Mike jones: You are geiing "out of range" error becuase you are going out of `str` range. Obviosuly your input file contains something else in addition to valid SSNs. It also contains strings that are shorter than SSNs, which is why you get this error. Quite likely, your input file ends with one or more empty lines (producing strings of zero length), which is exactly what makes it crash.

Comment: You said that your outputs incluide `500-18-7127`. How is that possible, considering that you are removing `-` characters from the string?

Comment: @AnT that is before erase, i will add the cout to the code right now.

Comment: @Mikejones if it crashes at the end, it means that you probably have an empty line as the last line of your file.

Comment: @vsoftco how would I prevent that  ?

Comment: @Mikejones Just edit the file and remove the blank line. Also, check R Sahu's answer below for how to do some bound checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest adding some checks to your code so you don't assume there are two `'-'`s where you expect to find them.

```
if ( str.size() >= 4 && str[3] == '-' )
{
   str.erase(3,1);
   if ( str.size() >= 6 && str[5] == '-' )
   {
      str.erase(5,1);
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "Did not find a '-' at the 6-th position of the string.\n";
      std::cout << str << std::endl;
   }
}
else
{
   std::cout << "Did not find a '-' at the 4-th position of the string.\n";
   std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, really helped. Just out of curiosity why do we check if the str.size() is >=4 ?

Comment: @Mikejones, `str.erase(3,1)` will try to erase the character at the 4-th position of the string. It does not make sense to call it unless the size of the string is 4 or more.